# Are there Korean keyboard layouts for OSX 10.9 that mimic the iOS 7 Korean layout?

Tags: keyboard, macos, internationalization

On my iOS7 devices (iPhone 5, iPad Air), I added a Korean keyboard and I can operate it effectively.

On the Macbook Air, I added the "3-Set Korean" input source and I cannot operate it effectively. (Some characters are not available, and those that are do not stack correctly. I am a beginning Korean writer.)

How can I get the iOS7 version of the Korean keyboard, or something very like it, to work on OSX Mavericks?

Comment: All characters should be available in the OS X input source.  If you give examples, someone can probably help.  I have heard of stacking failures in iOS 7 but not OS X. Please provide details of those too, and someone may be able to help.

Comment: If you like iOS, you should start by using 2-set and not 3-set.

Answer (score 1):

Switch to the 2-Set keyboard layout.  Let us know in detail if there is anything about that which is not working the way you want.